# Count unique with criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need a bit of help,

I am in need of counting a few things but I need to ensure they are unique to avoid a duplication issue.

So here it is

```
Column 1       Column2      Column3 
 1030           12344        1030
```

So if column 1 and 3 match count column 3 if unique.

```
=COUNTIFS('Signature '!J$3:J$1048576,L2)
```

But I need to be able to check to ensure it's not counting a row twice if it's a duplicate.

Alternatively I can just remove the counted duplicates if. I can I check the count just the unique numbers in C2.

[image: https://ibb.co/hgb99FR]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I wanted to count unique numbers in a excel and combine it with a countifs function](https://superuser.com/questions/616069/i-wanted-to-count-unique-numbers-in-a-excel-and-combine-it-with-a-countifs-funct)

Comment: You could make a pivot table first, then pivot it on a copy of the pivot table to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($J$2:$J$9999=L2,$D$2:$D$9999),$D$2:$D$9999)>0))`

This is an array formula and must be entered with ctrl+shift+enter. In cell `M2` press `F2` then paste then ctrl+shift+enter. From there, you can ctrl+c `M2` and copy down.

It's adapted from an explanation of using FREQUENCY to count unique with criteria that you can find at www dot exceljet dot net.

Comment: Alex, I literally just saw your post, Thank you for replying! I am going to give this a try. It most likely works better then mine 

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))

Where Data is the range where you have data.

Try tables out!

Comment: I’ll try this out as soon as I get home! Thank you. I typically use tables but I am giving this as a template and it has to be idiot proof. They are coping Dara from another report here and I’m worried if I use a table someone some where will some how will screw it up :)

Comment: No, that didn't work. I am able to use just COUNTIFS to compare and do a single cost the issue is column D may contain duplicates which means I'm counting column J twice. ideally I'd only want to count unique fields or remove duplicates automatically once the information is pasted into the excel.

Comment: Is it possible to train your end-users to paste things into a table, then run a bunch of power query off of that table?

Comment: It's possible however the end user may not be the only one to ever use it. We did a test run this morning and it came out pretty horrible. I ended up using a VBA macro to delete duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

`=SUMIFS('Order Data'!AI:AI,'Order Data'!C:C,A:A)`

Which worked out great

Comment: Not clear how columns AI, C or A relate to the question as posted

Comment: No, but for the final output I place the value on a separate page to give it a clean look but for sake of ease and to prevent confusion while asking the question I pasted everything in a single sheet. I can easily link to other sheets for the data but I felt like posting 2 different screenshots of 2 different sheets would cause confusion. Driver data and the total remain on 1 sheet and isn't altered while the reference data is on another and is altered by the user. Does that make sense? but the answer whatever the formula is I can link back to those sheets without confusing those who helped me

Comment: I get where you're coming from but it's kind of a community norm (it seems; I'm fairly new here myself) to write answers that correspond to the data in the question - you'll note that the arrangement of data in my answer matched that of your question - perhaps this answer works for you but it's of little use to other users who may have the same/similar question, and it's difficult to evaluate its worth as an answer when the data doesn't match. Put simply, if this answer were submitted by someone not the asker, it would probably receive downvotes.

Comment: That makes a really good point Alex, one I selfishly hadn't considered. Thank you! moving forward instead of trying to simplify it I'll post in it's entirety to better help the community. Thanks for your feedback man!